# executable file not found with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I come across this error:

> Cannot start service dashboard: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "npm": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

When I **build** the Dockerfile and run it, it works. When I run the service via docker-compose (docker-compose build --> docker-compose run dashboard), the error appears.

I thinks i

This is my Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM node:16
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install -g pnpm
RUN pnpm install
COPY . .
ARG APP_MOUNT_URI
ARG API_URI
ARG STATIC_URL
ENV API_URI ${API_URI:-http://localhost:8000/graphql/}
ENV APP_MOUNT_URI ${APP_MOUNT_URI:-/}
ENV STATIC_URL ${STATIC_URL:-/}

EXPOSE 9000
CMD npm start -- --hostname 0.0.0.0
```

here is my simplified docker-compose:

```sh
version: "2"
services:
  dashboard:
    image: saleor-plateform-dashboard
    build:
      context: ../saleor-dashboard
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - saleor-dashboard:/app:cached
      - /app/node_modules/
    command: npm start

volumes:
  saleor-dashboard:
    driver: local
  
networks:
  saleor-backend-tier:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: There seems to be a lot you don't need in this Compose setup.  In particular, the `volumes:` setup seems odd, mostly in that this creates a setup where it's impossible to update the code.  If you delete the `volumes:` blocks do you have the same problem?  (The `networks:` is unnecessary and unused, and you should not need the `command:` or `image:` overrides either.)

Comment: CMD should use exec form in Dockerfile: `CMD ["npm", "start", "--hostname 0.0.0.0"]` to take advantage of proper process signal behaviour.

Comment: @araisch Make sure to specify one shell word to a JSON-array item; I'd expect `CMD ["npm", "start", "--", "--hostname", "0.0.0.0"]`.  But it doesn't matter if you override it with a Compose `command:` (which is why I suggest deleting the Compose override).

Comment: Oh missed that in quick reshaping, thanks. Yes, was consecutive to your remark deleting the `command:` for sure..

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze, I remove volumes and replace it by the path of the folder and it work